Why this family of Hamiltonian being introduced when dealing with system under Periodic Boundary Condition?
While studying the large system under periodic boundary conditions, a family of Hamiltonian is introduced  which is ,
$\hat{H}(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^{N} {(p_i -\hbar\alpha)}^2+  \hat{V}$
$\alpha $ is a real constant and $\hat{V}$ is the many body potential.
I am not able to understand why only such type of Hamiltonian is introduced here and what does it signifies?
For reference see equation (5) of
https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9709306
